# 'AmazonDynamoDBClient.PutItem(PutItemRequest)' is inaccessible due to its protection level'

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb

New user to dynamodb and trying to integrate this with my .net core.

I have used the example at:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LowLevelDotNetItemsExample.html

Below is the sample example:

```
private static string tableName = "ProductCatalog";
private static AmazonDynamoDBClient client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();

private static void CreateItem()
{
        var request = new PutItemRequest
        {
            TableName = tableName,
            Item = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>()
        {
            { "Id", new AttributeValue {
                  N = "1000"
              }},
            { "Title", new AttributeValue {
                  S = "Book 201 Title"
              }},
            { "ISBN", new AttributeValue {
                  S = "11-11-11-11"
              }},
            { "Authors", new AttributeValue {
                  SS = new List<string>{"Author1", "Author2" }
              }},
            { "Price", new AttributeValue {
                  N = "20.00"
              }},
            { "Dimensions", new AttributeValue {
                  S = "8.5x11.0x.75"
              }},
            { "InPublication", new AttributeValue {
                  BOOL = false
              } }
        }
        };
        client.PutItem(request);
    }
```

But when I run the code I get the errors:

```
Error   CS0122  'AmazonDynamoDBClient.PutItem(PutItemRequest)' is inaccessible due to its protection level
Error   CS0122  'AmazonDynamoDBClient.GetItem(GetItemRequest)' is inaccessible due to its protection level
and so on for all the request.
```

What is missing here?

Thanks

Comment: There seems to be a problem with your AmazonDynamoDBClient object accessibility. I have added the C# tag, someone in that community will be able to answer pretty quickly I think.

Comment: @Stu I am just using the same as shared by amazon in the above link. What I found out was there are async methods available for ex client.PutItemAsync instead of PutItem. Not sure why amazon have mentioned that way. Have posted this at amazon forum but did not received any reply there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like we have to use async method for .net core in interacting with dynamo db.

More information can be found at : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforxamarin/developerguide/dynamodb-integration-docmodel.html

Though the link is for mobile platform but that is what I found out and works.